# Resizing image with cv2

Tags: python, tensorflow, opencv

I'm trying resize images retrieved from cifar10 in the original 32x32 to 96x96 for use with MobileNetV2, howevery I'm running into this error. Tried a variety of solutions but nothing seems to work.

My code:

```
for a in range(len(train_images)):
    train_images[a] = cv2.resize(train_images[a], dsize=(minSize, minSize), interpolation=cv2.INTER_CUBIC)
```

Error I'm getting:

```
----> 8     train_images[a] = cv2.resize(train_images[a], dsize=(minSize, minSize), interpolation=cv2.INTER_CUBIC)
ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (96,96,3) into shape (32,32,3)
```

Comment: Since you're not using the index `a` in anything else, you could change the `for` loop into `for img in train_images:` and replace `train_images[a]` by `img`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is simply because you are reading the 32x32 image from train_images and trying to save the reshaped image (96x96) in the same array which is impossible! 
Try something like:

```
train_images_reshaped = np.array((num_images, 96, 96, 3))
for a in range(len(train_images)):
    train_images_reshaped[a] = cv2.resize(train_images[a], dsize=(minSize, minSize), interpolation=cv2.INTER_CUBIC)
```

Comment: So the image in the array can't be replaced?

Comment: No, because the original numpy array size is fixed.

Comment: It can be replaced.

Comment: The error no longer appears when I append it into a new array. Any idea how I can check if the images are indeed resized?

Comment: I printed out length of the image before and after, value did indeed change from 32 to 96. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes you have to convert the image from RGB to grayscale. If that is the problem, the only thing you should do is `gray_image = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)`, *resize the image* and then again `resized_image = cv2.cvtColor(gray_image, cv2.COLOR_GRAY2RGB)`

I have never run into this error but if the first option doesn't work, you can try and resize image with pillow like this:

```
from PIL import Image

im = Image.fromarray(cv2_image)
nx, ny = im.size
im2 = im.resize((nx*2, ny*2), Image.LANCZOS)
cv2_image = cv2.cvtColor(numpy.array(im2), cv2.COLOR_RGB2BGR)
```

You can make this into a function and call it in the list comprehension. I hope this solves your problem :)

Comment: Thanks for the answer anyway, I upvoted it back up to make it not negative anymore, apparently some guy down voted all the answers in this page.

managed to get it working by reassigning and appending it to a new array instead of replacing. And I not sure if changing to gray scale will affect the results, so I'll just stick with not replacing for now! THanks anyway

Comment: The number of channels (monochrome vs RGB or BGR) is not the issue. As Ary pointed out in [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52875926/8856893), the issue is that the OP is trying to save an array of shape (96, 96, 3) in a fixed-size array subset of shape (32, 32, 3).

Answer (score 0):

There are some interpolation algorithms in OpenCV. Such as-

- INTER_NEAREST – a nearest-neighbor interpolation
- INTER_LINEAR – a bilinear interpolation (used by default)
- INTER_AREA – resampling using pixel area relation. It may be a
  preferred method for image decimation, as it gives moire’-free
  results. But when the image is zoomed, it is similar to the
  INTER_NEAREST method.
- INTER_CUBIC – a bicubic interpolation over 4×4 pixel  neighborhood
- INTER_LANCZOS4 – a Lanczos interpolation over 8×8 pixel  neighborhood

**Code:**

```
image_scaled=cv2.resize(image,None,fx=.75,fy=.75,interpolation = cv2.INTER_LINEAR)
img_double=cv2.resize(image,None,fx=2,fy=2,interpolation=cv2.INTER_CUBIC)
image_resize=cv2.resize(image,(200,300),interpolation=cv2.INTER_AREA)
image_resize=cv2.resize(image,(500,400),interpolation=cv2.INTER_LANCZOS4)
```

You can find the details about **python implementation** here as well: [How to resize images in OpenCV python](https://www.life2coding.com/how-to-resize-images-in-opencv-python-using-different-interpolation-methods/)